# php bad word content filter

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have a content filter that works, it just doesn't work like i want it to.
for example if i said "badword you i badword hate you" the entire thing is outputted as "[CONTENT DELETED]" but i want it to say "******* you i ******* hate you"

```
<?php

function SecurePost($var) {
  return trim($DBcon->real_escape_string($var));
}

function filter($string) {
  $words = array("badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere", "badwordhere");
  $new =   array("****", "*****", "***", "*******", "****", "****", "*****", "******", "*****", "******", "*****", "***", "*******", "***", "****", "***", "*****", "*******", "****", "****", "*****", "****", "****", "****", "******");
  $string1 = str_ireplace($words, $new, $string);
  $findme = "***";
  $pos = strpos($string1, $findme);
  if ($pos !== false) {
    $string1 = "[ Content Deleted ]";
    return $string1;
  }
  else {
    return $string1;
  }
}

function SecureString($value) {
  $value = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(strip_tags($value)));
  return $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: This is an impossible task, you can catch bad words *(with a very long dictionary)* but you can't catch all variants of these words: `FuUuCk`, `b1owJ0b`... In short, trying to do that is only a waste of time and doesn't replace a moderator. News: we are now in 2017, you can without risk stop to use all `mysql_` functions.

Comment: I know i cant stop them all, that wasnt my question....

Comment: Perhaps, but it is my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few bugs in the code. Please check below working example:

```
<?php
$str = "Kiss my badwordhere";
echo filter($str) . "\n";

$str = "badwordhere anywherebadword";
echo filter($str) . "\n";


function filter($string) {
  $words = array("badwordhere", "anywherebadword");
  $new =   array("****", "*******");
  $string1 = str_ireplace($words, $new, $string);
  $left = preg_replace("/[\* ]+/", "", $string1);
  if (strlen($left) == 0) {
    $string1 = "[ Content Deleted ]";
    return $string1;
  }
  else {
    return $string1;
  }
}
?>
```

prints

```
Kiss my ****
[ Content Deleted ]
```